# How can we best prepare for graduation from Beta status?

Tags: discussion

Hello Korean Language SE community!

In December of this year, there are plans to move our site from a beta site to a **full site**. This is an important step. A very important step. I have been a moderator for this community for 5 and 1/2 years and I am pleased with how much we have grown.

- What feedback do you have for the site?
- How can we improve?
- What do you think will generate more traffic and quality questions and answers for our site?

Thank you for each of your contributions. Moving to full site status is a reflection of the work that all of you have put in to make this a positive and impactful community.

More details will be provided later as we learn more.

Thanks!